# Production has 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In our tool, we will be consuming webapi service. This webapi service and our Tool works only Intranet domain based on windows authentication. There is no username and password required to call webapi service. This service is open for all the application only in Intranet domain.

In our tool, same controller multiple places we will be calling webApi methods (same code provided below) to get data. DEV, QA, UAT and DR the webapi service is working fine and giving expected output. But only one in Production it is throwing below error. We tried changing authoring setting in IIS. But it does not help.

> Error message: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid
>   credentials.

**Option 1**

1. Open iis and select the website that is causing the 401
2. Open the “Authentication” property under the “IIS” header
3. Click the “Windows Authentication” item and click “Providers”
4. Move NTLM at top

**Option 2:**

1. Open IIS Manager and select the website that is causing the 401
2. Open the "Authentication" property under the "IIS" header
3. Click the "Windows Authentication" item and click "Advanced Settings" from the right
4. Set "Extended Protection" to "OFF"

   ```
       string parameterURI = "testMethod2/" + 1011;       
       RestClient client = new RestClient(webApiUrl);
       client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
       RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(parameterURI, Method.GET);
       IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
   ```

Expected result should be: JSON Data

Error message: 
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Since it is Banking and Insurance domain. I'm not able to provide correct out data from service.

Comment: Did you remove the anonymous authentication option?

Comment: Anonymous Authentication disabled and Windows Authentication is enabled in production

Comment: If you're using Windows authentication, what user is the production app pool running as? Does that user has permission to access the web service? (It's not the data we need to see, it's configuration like this.)

Comment: Can you please guide. How to get this details of production app pool running as? I'm not aware of IIS much.

Comment: I don't have an IIS installation handy - I'll try and find one - but on the left under your server you should see 'Application Pools', and somewhere in the application configuration there will be a property that selects one of these pools for your app to run on. Each pool has a user assigned that it runs as, probably a domain user on the production server, but often a local user on other servers. If you're using Windows Authentication then you're trying to authenticate to the API endpoint as that user, the user that the application pool that your app is configured to use is running as.

Comment: You need to make sure that this is all set up as you'd expect: that there exists an application pool on the server with the correct .NET version for your app and running as the domain user that you're expecting your app to run as, and that your app is configured to use that pool, and that this user has permission to access your production web endpoint (is in the right groups?) over Windows Authentication.

Comment: .Net CLR version: v4.0.30319 and Managed pipeline: Integrated. Tool developed in dotnet version: 4.0

Comment: All user has access to the Tool, all the screens are working fine as expected. Only the problem where webapi service calling screen and MVC controllers.

Comment: I meant the 'Identity' column on the Application Pools tab. This likely needs to be a domain user if you're using Windows Authentication: if it's 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' then that's probably wrong, because it'll be a server-local user with no access to resources on other servers. You can find which app pool you're using in 'Advanced Settings' on the top level of the website.